# trigger to convert all phone numbers entered into (999) 999-9999 format

Tags: oracle, triggers

Need help with the substr part. The code doesn't work because I do not know how to format it.I am not sure whether to use substr or not. I need the code to convert all phone numbers entered into (999) 999-9999 format.Need help with implementing a trigger that would reformat phone numbers to the format (999) 999-9999 throughout the vendors table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER vendors_phone_fix
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF vendor_phone
ON vendors 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
**Substr(:
      :new.vendor_phone := Substr**(
END; 
/
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

For now I'm stuck with the first code above and I don't know how to format the phone number to look like the (800) phone numbers.

[SO I want the 713 phone number to look like the (800) phone number using triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJomw.png)